# Logout button keeps going to my error page rather than logging out? PHP

Tags: php

I have a system set up where my site needs to know who's logged in which is saved when logged in and their encryption which are is stored in a text document on in my directories. If either of these are tampered with the site goes to my error page which works perfectly, however when I isset my logout to destroy the session it goes to my error page rather than my index. Anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

```
<?php
ob_clean();session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
}
else{
    if (isset($_GET['Username'])){  
        if (isset($_GET['Encryption'])){    
            $Username = $_GET['Username'];
            $Encryption = $_GET['Encryption'];

            if (is_dir("USERS/".$Username) === true) {
                if($Encryption == file_get_contents("USERS/".$Username."/Encryption.txt")){
                    $NoOfDocs = file_get_contents("USERS/".$Username."/NoOfDocuments.txt"); 
                }
                else{
                    header("Location: 201Error.php");
                }
            }   
            else{
                header("Location: 201Error.php");
            }
        }
    }
}

if(empty($Username)){
    header("Location: 201Error.php");
}

if (empty($Encryption)){
    header("Location: 201Error.php");
}

?>
```

**EDIT 1**
Okay so i've tried changing

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
}
```

to

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit(); 
}
```

and

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();  
}
```

and they both are still providing me with the same result, sending me to my error page. (Thanks for the help here by the way) :)

**EDIT 2**
Here is my php on my index page it all looks fine to me, but there might be something i'm missing?

```
<?php
ob_clean();session_start(); 

if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
}

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
    header("Location: Home.php");
}

$Username = $_POST['username'];
$EnteredPassword = $_POST['password'];


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if (empty($Username)){
        echo '<font color="#FF0000"><p align="center">Username or Password incorrect please try again</p></font>';
    }
    else {      
        if (is_dir("USERS/".$Username) === true){
            $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Password.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
            $CorrectPassword = fgets($myFile);
            fclose($myFile);

            if ($CorrectPassword == $EnteredPassword){
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                $Encryption = file_get_contents("USERS/".$Username."/Encryption.txt") or exit("Can't write file!");
                header("Location: Home.php?isset=true&Username=$Username&Encryption=$Encryption");      
            }

            else {
                echo '<font color="#FF0000"><p align="center">Username or Password incorrect please try again</p></font>';
            }
        }

        else {
            echo '<font color="#FF0000"><p align="center">Username or Password incorrect please try again</p></font>';
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['Error'])){
    $Error = $_GET['Error'];
    if ($Error == '201'){
        echo '<font color="#FF0000"><p align="center">Unfortunately, a security protocol has been invoked and therefore you have been logged out.</p></font>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you please show us logout url?

Comment: mysite.com?logout

Comment: yupp.. right.. you need to redirect after session destroy and exit() after that

Comment: I've updated my post with the current results but still no joy.

Comment: still the same error appear?

Comment: The exact same results yes.

Comment: can you please put exit() after all header

Comment: it will solved you issue most probably

Comment: Still no joy adding the exit() on the end off all the headers. I've also commented out all the code after the if isset logout statement, so all the header errors cannot run and it's still sending me there... HOW?

Comment: i run your code in my pc it working fine.....may issue in your index.php page..check it out index.php

Comment: So i've made a second edit adding my php for my index page, I can't seem to see anything wrong with it but like I said I may have missed something.

Comment: Okay I think I've cracked it, I removed all the php on all the pages that were involved and only added the code needed for this process and it all worked. So i'll take good look into it thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i've solved the problem I removed the if empty statements as there isn't any need for them anyway as if the username and key isn't the same anyway it will be invoked so therefore if it's empty it isn't the same and they are then logged out. Now I also had some help from Kamlesh Gupta which has solved the main issues. So all in all the code now looks like this.

```
<?php
ob_clean();
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();  // need to put exit after header if you don't need to go further
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit(); 
}
else{
    if (isset($_GET['Username'])){  
        if (isset($_GET['Encryption'])){    
            $Username = $_GET['Username'];
            $Encryption = $_GET['Encryption'];

            if (is_dir("USERS/".$Username) === true) {
                if($Encryption == file_get_contents("USERS/".$Username."/Encryption.txt")){
                    $NoOfDocs = file_get_contents("USERS/".$Username."/NoOfDocuments.txt"); 
                }
                else{
                    header("Location: 201Error.php");exit();    
                }
            }   
            else{
                header("Location: 201Error.php");exit();    
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks for all your help guys :)